What could be causing the namespace CPU quota request to exceed the sum of the pod CPU requests?
I'm facing a puzzling situation with resource usage in my Kubernetes namespace.
Namespace Quota:
Resource    Used     Hard
--------    ----     ----
count/pods  94       300
cpu         17800m   32
memory      66949Mi  192Gi

The namespace is reporting 17800m (17.8 cores) of CPU request quota usage. However, when I sum the CPU requests of all the pods in the namespace, the total is significantly lower (around 12 cores). I don't understand the source of this discrepancy.
Things I've checked:
Horizontal Pod Autoscalers (HPA): No HPAs are active in the namespace.
Pod Requests: All pods have CPU requests defined.
What could be causing the namespace CPU quota usage to exceed the sum of the pod CPU requests?
Are there any other factors or hidden components that could be consuming CPU resources?

Can you check whether you have any pending pods? If you have defined any resources in the kubernetes definitions that might also be counted against resource quota.

I have pods with init containers? If Ihave an init container with a larger request then the sum of the request for normal containers, then the pods CPU request will be that of the largest init container.
For example:
Pod has an init container with 1000m CPU request Pod has 2 normal containers requesting 250m CPU each
In this case myeffective CPU request for the pod is not 500m as some people would think, but rather 1000m.
Myeffective request is the larger of these two things: The largest request for that resource for any individual init container The sum of the requests for that resource for all of your normal containers combined.

it's the answer. it was because of the init container request.
